# What does "to be on white knuckles on Nemesis or the Energiser" mean in other words?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Please, explain the phrase given in bold below in details:

Britain’s No 1 theme park
with more mega thrills than ever, set in 20 acres of stunning parkland!
**So whether you’re after white knuckles on Nemesis or the Energiser, or pleasant green acres, there’s something for everyone!**

Answer (score 2):

"White knuckles" is an idiom for "intense apprehension or fear".  The image is of someone gripping some supporting structure *so tightly* that the knuckles of their fingers turn white.

[image]

Roller coasters and other "thrill" rides are designed to induce an enjoyable level of fear.  For some people, the more fear, the better.  Hence a "white-knuckle ride" is an attraction, and, at this amusement park, apparently two of these are named the *Nemesis* and the *Energiser*.

The ad suggests that whether you are looking for the excitement of a roller coaster ride, or just looking to relax in "green acres" (woods, parks, etc.), this amusement park can provide both.

As an American, the phrasing seems a little odd to me, but it's probably perfect natural UK English.

Comment: @sharur  As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an ad for a theme park, claiming to have both exciting/thrilling/scary rollercoaster, etc. rides and calm, serene green space.

"To be after white knuckles" is an understandable phrase, but a bit unusual to an American English speaker, that I would generally interpret to mean seeking thrills/scares/adrenaline rush, which they claim their rides can deliver.

Basically, they are trying to to communicate "We have both active excitement and calm places in our theme park".

Comment: I think you mean *ad*, not *add*. And "to be after [something]" is not an odd phrase at all. It's pretty commonplace for native speakers.

Comment: @Robusto: Thank you for your feedback; I have edited my answer to address your complaints. As a native American English speaker, this phrase is odd to me, in the sense that it is unusual and not common place. Not, "To be after", but rather "To be after white knuckles"; I have been more likely to seen a usage of "be after thrills" or "be after excitement". I understand the usage of "white knuckles" as a synecdoche, but I find its usage is unusual, or as I originally put it, "odd".